calling a View struct method from ContentView doesn't update View's @State variable
I'm learning SwiftUI via HackingWithSwift. In my ContentView, I have 12 Button views that I made as a separate struct MultiplicationTableButton that I include in ContentView via ForEach. My goal (and challenge for this project) is to animate the button that was selected by rotating it forward, and then rotate any previously selected button backward. The function that selects the button that was selected (and deselects all the rest of the buttons) is in ContentView as selectMultiplicationTable(number:). In the Button's action:, it runs a closure provided to it upon initialization that is stored in the Button's struct, that in turn runs ContentView.selectMultiplicationTable(number:), which then runs each Button's select() or deselect() method based on if that was the button that was selected.
It works to where it runs select() or deselect() on all the Buttons, but the degreesToRotate @State property doesn't update. It should increment or decrement by 360, but it remains at 0.0:
func select() -> Void {
    print(self.degreesToRotate) // Starts at 0.0
        
    self.degreesToRotate += 360 // Should increment to 360.0
        
    print(self.degreesToRotate) // Stays at 0.0
        
    self.isSelected = true
}

I notice in the Button's action:, if I run the Button's select() method itself instead of the provided onSelect() closure that was provided on initialization, the animation works:
Button("\(number)") {
        //
        // Run onSelect()
        //
        //self.onSelect() // This doesn't make the animation run.
        self.select() // This will actually make the animation run.
    }

Here's my entire code:
import SwiftUI



//
// Use hex for Color initializer.
//
extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        }

        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(r) / 255,
            green: Double(g) / 255,
            blue:  Double(b) / 255,
            opacity: Double(a) / 255
        )
    }
}



//
// Multiplication Table Buttons Modifier.
//
struct MultiplicationTableButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    let fillColor:   String
    let strokeColor: String
    
    
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(hex: self.fillColor))
                    .stroke(Color(hex: self.strokeColor), lineWidth: 3)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
    }
}



//
// Extend View with our ViewModifiers
//
extension View {
    func multiplicationTableButtonStyle(
        fillColor: String,
        strokeColor: String
    ) -> some View {
        modifier(
            MultiplicationTableButtonModifier(
                fillColor:      fillColor,
                strokeColor:    strokeColor
            )
        )
    }
}



//
// struct MultiplicationTableButton
//
struct MultiplicationTableButton: View {
    let number:         Int
    let fillColor:      String
    let strokeColor:    String
    let onSelect:       () -> Void
    
    @State private var degreesToRotate  = 0.0
    @State private var isSelected       = false
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("\(number)") {
            //
            // Run onSelect()
            //
            self.onSelect()
            //self.select()
        }
        .multiplicationTableButtonStyle(
            fillColor: fillColor,
            strokeColor: strokeColor
        )
        .foregroundStyle(self.isSelected ? .black : .white)
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(
            Circle()
                .fill(Color(hex: self.isSelected ? "fff" : "fc4c4c"))
                .stroke(
                    Color(hex: self.isSelected ? "000" : "ca1919"),
                    lineWidth: 3
                )
        )
        .padding(.horizontal, 7)
        .rotation3DEffect(
            .degrees(self.degreesToRotate),
            axis: (
                x: (1...4).contains(self.number) ?   1 : 0,
                y: (5...8).contains(self.number) ?   1 : 0,
                z: (9...12).contains(self.number) ?  1 : 0
            )
        )
        .animation(.default, value: self.isSelected)
    }
    
    
    
    func select() -> Void {
        print(self.degreesToRotate)
        
        self.degreesToRotate += 360
        
        print(self.degreesToRotate)
        
        self.isSelected = true
    }
    
    
    
    func deselect() -> Void {
        self.degreesToRotate -= 360
        self.isSelected = false
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    static var multiplicationTableButtons: [MultiplicationTableButton] = []
    
    static let tableColors = [
        1: (fill: "fc4c4c", stroke: "ca1919"),
        2: (fill: "fcab4c", stroke: "ca7919"),
        3: (fill: "fcdd4c", stroke: "c1b207"),
        4: (fill: "50e316", stroke: "2eaf10"),
        5: (fill: "5ef7b4", stroke: "19ca81"),
        6: (fill: "4cf6fc", stroke: "19abca"),
        7: (fill: "4cabfc", stroke: "196cca"),
        8: (fill: "4c54fc", stroke: "1b10a5"),
        9: (fill: "9f4cfc", stroke: "5e11b4"),
        10: (fill: "dd4cfc", stroke: "ab19ca"),
        11: (fill: "fc4ca7", stroke: "ca196c"),
        12: (fill: "b46e09", stroke: "7b4514")
    ]
    
    @State private var gameState = "settings"
    
    
    
    init() {
        //
        // Make and store our Multiplication Table Buttons.
        //
        for buttonNumber in 1...12 {
            Self.multiplicationTableButtons.append(
                MultiplicationTableButton(
                    number:         buttonNumber,
                    fillColor:      Self.tableColors[buttonNumber]!.fill,
                    strokeColor:    Self.tableColors[buttonNumber]!.stroke,
                    onSelect: {
                        //
                        // Call ContentView.selectMultiplicationTable()
                        //
                        Self.selectMultiplicationTable(number: buttonNumber)
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        //
        // Settings View
        //
        if gameState == "settings" {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Choose your multiplication table")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self) { number in
                            ContentView.multiplicationTableButtons[number]
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                    
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(4..<8, id: \.self) { number in
                            ContentView.multiplicationTableButtons[number]
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                    
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(8..<12, id: \.self) { number in
                            ContentView.multiplicationTableButtons[number]
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                }
                .navigationTitle("EduTables")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .border(.green)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        
        
        
        //
        // Game View
        //
        if gameState == "game" {
            
        }
    }
    
    
    
    static func selectMultiplicationTable(number: Int) -> Void {
        for i in 0..<Self.multiplicationTableButtons.count {
            if Self.multiplicationTableButtons[i].number == number {
                Self.multiplicationTableButtons[i].select()
            } else {
                Self.multiplicationTableButtons[i].deselect()
            }
        }
        
        /*
        for button in Self.multiplicationTableButtons {
            if button.number == number {
                button.select()
            } else {
                button.deselect()
            }
        }
         */
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Thanks for helping a newbie!

SwiftUI has no way of observing a static property. I suggest looking at some basic tutorials

Allow me to offer a more streamlined way (and code) to go about achieving what you're after, by addressing some points:

Since you already have a MultiplicationTableButton view where you style the button, there is no need for the ViewModifier. You could apply the fill and stroke directly in MultiplicationTableButton. Alternatively, if you do actually have a need for a separate ViewModifier for styling, then use that and don't include the same styling in MultiplicationTableButton.

If your fill and stroke colors were completely different (blue fill and red stroke, for example), it would make sense to have a parameter for each. But since your fill and stroke are basically the same color, you can achieve the same result by simply passing a color and changing the other one based on it. Say the color is .blue, you could set it as the stroke and then the fill would be .blue.opacity(0.5). The code below uses this method.

Each button should be self contained and reactive based on the selected number. The selected number should be a state shared with all buttons. Tapping a button will set that state with the value of the tapped button. You do this via a @Binding to a @State in the parent view (the grid of buttons). Like this, every button can react to changes of the selected number, simplifying logic and code.


For example, to rotate one direction or another, it can be as simple as:
.onChange(of: selectedNumber) {         
    rotationAngle += selectedNumber == number ? 360 : -360
}

This means that:

You don't need a state to determine if it's selected or not. Not relying on a state means one less state to worry about keeping in sync, especially if it's essential to other functionality.
You don't need separate select() or deselect() functions.
If anything, you can simplify the condition selectedNumber == number by making it a computed property (as shown in the full code below).



I really don't get the point of having an initializer to populate an array of buttons based on an array of colors. You could use the array of the colors to call the button view inside a loop in the body, since you have a loop there anyway.

You can simply use a Grid to achieve the 4-column layout you want, instead of building it manually using 3 different loops. In fact, that's a big no no, since it doesn't scale - what if your array had 120 items?

Your overall layout should be something like : Main View > Grid View > Button Views. In your code, you're building the grid manually, meaning that if you want to display that grid elsewhere, you can't simply call something like: MultiplicationTableGrid().


Hope this helps. The goal is to simplify logic and code, all while offering more flexibility:
import SwiftUI

struct MultiplicationNumberMainView: View {
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //Caption
            Text("Select a number:")
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            
            //Grid view
            MultiplicationNumberGrid()
        }
    }
}

struct MultiplicationNumberGrid: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var selectedNumber: Int?
    
    //An array of 12 colors
    private let colors: [Color] = [
        .red, .blue, .green, .yellow,
        .purple, .orange, .pink, .gray,
        .cyan, .teal, .indigo, .brown
    ]
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            //A four column grid for 12 items
            Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { row in
                    GridRow {
                        ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self) { column in
                            let index = row * 4 + column
                            let number = index + 1
                            RoundMultiplicationButton(number: number, color: colors[index], selectedNumber: $selectedNumber)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Reset button
            Button("Reset"){
                selectedNumber = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RoundMultiplicationButton: View {
    
    //Parameters
    let number: Int
    let color: Color
    @Binding var selectedNumber: Int?
    
    //State values
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0.0
    @State private var rotateClockwise = false // State to toggle rotation direction

    //Computed properties
    private var isSelected: Bool {
        selectedNumber == number
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            selectedNumber = number
        } label : {
            Text("\(number)")
            
                //Text styling
                .foregroundStyle(color)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .shadow(color: .white, radius: 0, x: 1, y: 1)
            
                //Size & background
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .background {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(color.opacity(0.4))
                        .stroke(color, lineWidth: 3)
                }
                .padding()
            
                //Selection styling (emphasize if selected)
                .opacity(rotationAngle == 0 ? 1 : isSelected ? 1 : 0.4)
                .scaleEffect(isSelected ? 1.3 : 1)
            
                //Animation
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: isSelected ? 0.3 : 1), value: rotationAngle)
            
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedNumber) {
            
            // Set rotation angle only if selected number is not nil, otherwise reset rotation
            guard selectedNumber != nil else {
                rotationAngle = 0
                return
            }
            
            rotationAngle += selectedNumber == number ? 360 : -360
        }
    }
}

//Previews
#Preview {
    MultiplicationNumberMainView()
}




Consider ForEach interface:
public struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable {

    /// The collection of underlying identified data that SwiftUI uses to create
    /// views dynamically.
    public var data: Data

    /// A function to create content on demand using the underlying data.
    public var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
}

content closure provide Data.Element and your job is return your View.
Now consider this example:
struct A {
    var val = 0
}

let a = A()

func createA() -> A {
    return a
}

var b = createA()
b.val = 2
print(a.val)

a.val is equal to 0, not equal to 2, a and b is not reference to the same memory.
So go back to your code:
ForEach(8..<12, id: \.self) { number in
    ContentView.multiplicationTableButtons[number]
}

It is the same as createA function above as View in SwiftUI is struct. Your onSelect closure not work because array element of value multiplicationTableButtons is not reference to current MultiplicationTableButton in SwiftUI view hiriechy.
